# Receive middle mouse click event

Tags: c++, event-handling, mouseevent

I want to know how I can receive the event of a middle mouse clicked in C++. Is there anyway to do so? If there is, how exactly can I implement this? I've read online that I can use WM_MBUTTONDOWN however I am really unfamiliar with using this and I've been told that it is indeed not even part of C++.

Answer (score 0):

WM_MBUTTONDOWN is defined as part of the Windows API. It is just an integer value that's recognized by the operating system. You can use C++ to compile a Windows application, although the language doesn't matter in this case.

A typical Windows application has a message loop. When a message is received by your application, you can decide what to do with it before passing it back for the next application to handle.

I recommend reading the [Forger's Guide](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/window_click.html).

Comment: OK so would you recommend I use the Windows API to tackle this problem? How would I implement the solution. I am really unfamiliar in  this aspect.

Comment: I'm not sure about implementing a solution with pure API. Depends on the scope of your project, and the framework choices you have, I suppose. Since you mentioned WM_MBUTTONDOWN, I know that the technical resource you're using is about WinAPI. I just want to make it clear that it is not part of a language, and it doesn't have to be part of C++.